# Equivalent battery

Tags: batteries, drone

I bought a drone with a battery and i would like to buy a second one.
Maybe a better one if possible.

I have a charger with wrote :

```
Li-PO: 7.4V
```

And the battery:

```
Full ymax 853480 (i guess it's reference ?)
7.4V 2000 mAh
14.8 Wh
+ 6154*3101
```

I have seen others battery, but never with same characteristic, Witch one is the most important ?

Does `7.4 V 800 mAh`

The identical are only on alibaba, so rather have a better one.

This is a picture of it

[image]

Comment: You should try to match the "7.4V 2000 mAh" - the 800mAh one has a much lower capacity and may not be suitable for the same charge/discharge currents.

Comment: Ok, so can i use 6000 mAh for exemple ? it could broke it ? Longer time battery ?

Comment: 6000mAh would work electrically, but may be too physically large or heavy.

Answer (score 1):

The ampere readings are very important when considering a battery for such usage. Fueling a drone requires a large amount of current flow. I guess it is not possible to power a drone with 800mAh battery. Find some battery that has the same current ratings. And to answer your question both of the Voltage and Current ratings are important.